# Удаление некоторых символов из TextField

Tags: xcode, ios, objective-c

Здравствуйте еще раз, второй вопрос которых я хотел спросить, это:
Как можно удалить некоторые символы из TextField по нажатию на Button. 
т.е. допустим у меня есть текст (номер телефона) - +7 (123) 456-78-90, после нажатия удаляются символы - @" +()- ",  получается: 71234567890.
Через textDidChange выполнять? Подскажите?)

Comment: Очень очень нужно, весь гугл обыскал, нигде не могу найти.

Comment: А в чём собственно проблема? Выполнить свой код при нажатии кнопки? Получить текст из `TextField` как строку? Отфильтровать символы в строке? Записать назад в `TextField` изменённый текст?

Comment: Да, мы тут все не пишем готовые ответы, затаившись в ожидании, что именно непонятно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSString* phoneNumber = [self.phoneTextField.text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
phoneNumber = [phoneNumber stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"+" withString:@""];
phoneNumber = [phoneNumber stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"(" withString:@""];
phoneNumber = [phoneNumber stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@")" withString:@""];
phoneNumber = [phoneNumber stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"-" withString:@""];
```

примерно так

Comment: Не работает :C, сделал все правильно

Comment: Только если без NSString, напрямую..